# show error message on the same page

Tags: jsf

I have a login form to authenticate a user against an active directory with LDAP. I use Apache Shiro for doing this (I believe this is not the important thing but I better mention this as it could have an impact on what I try to get to work). In case a user inputs wrong password an exception is being thrown for which I'd like to show an error message on same page where my form is. Therefore I wrote a custom exception handler as recommended where I specify the error message. Here are the relevant parts of the code:

index.xhtml (my login form):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
>

<h:form>
    <h:messages globalOnly="false"/>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:outputLabel for="username">Username:</h:outputLabel>
        <h:inputText id="username" value="#{user.userName}"/>
        <h:outputLabel for="password">Password:</h:outputLabel>
        <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{user.password}"/>
        <h:message for="username" infoStyle="color:darkgreen" errorStyle="color:red"/>
        <h:message for="password" infoStyle="color:darkgreen" errorStyle="color:red"/>
    </h:panelGrid>
    <h:commandButton value="Login" action="#{loginController.login}" rendered="#{!loginController.loggedIn}"/>
    <h:commandButton value="Logout" action="#{loginController.logout}" rendered="#{loginController.loggedIn}"/>
</h:form>
</html>
```

Login method from the LoginController class:

```
public String login() {
        currentUser = ldapUserProvider.provide(); //gets Apache Shiro's Subject which is the user being authenticated.
        if (!currentUser.isAuthenticated()) {
            CustomUsernamePasswordToken token = new CustomUsernamePasswordToken(DOMAIN, user.getUserName(), user.getPassword());
            token.setRememberMe(true);
            try {
                currentUser.login(token); //this one causes exception if the password is wrong, for example
                loggedIn = true;
                return "success.xhtml";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "index.xhtml"; //in this case I'd like to show the error message and prompt to login again
            }
        }
        return "index.xhtml";
    }
```

Custom ExceptionHandler:

```
package com.flyeralarm.tools.apss;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandler;
import javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerWrapper;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.context.Flash;
import javax.faces.event.ExceptionQueuedEvent;
import javax.faces.event.ExceptionQueuedEventContext;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class AuthenticationExceptionHanlder extends ExceptionHandlerWrapper {
    private ExceptionHandler wrappedExceptionhandler;

    public AuthenticationExceptionHanlder(final ExceptionHandler wrappedExceptionhandler) {
        this.wrappedExceptionhandler = wrappedExceptionhandler;
    }

    @Override
    public ExceptionHandler getWrapped() {
        return wrappedExceptionhandler;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle() {
        Iterator<ExceptionQueuedEvent> eventIterator = getUnhandledExceptionQueuedEvents().iterator();
        while (eventIterator.hasNext()) {
            ExceptionQueuedEvent event = eventIterator.next();
            ExceptionQueuedEventContext eventContext = (ExceptionQueuedEventContext) event.getSource();
            Throwable exception = eventContext.getException();
            handleException(exception, eventContext);
            eventIterator.remove();
            getWrapped().handle();
        }
    }

    private void handleException(Throwable exception, ExceptionQueuedEventContext context) {
        FacesMessage exceptionMessage = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Login failed.", exception.getMessage());
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        Flash flash = facesContext.getExternalContext().getFlash(); //I read that putting the message into flash would do the work but it didn't
        flash.put("errorDetails", exception.getMessage());
        facesContext.addMessage(null, exceptionMessage);
        facesContext.getApplication().getNavigationHandler().handleNavigation(facesContext, null, "index?faces-redirect=true");
    }
}
```

I also tried different combinations with  being global only = true and false and  but the page still doesn't show the error message I defined in the custom exception handler. Am I doing smth. wrong?

Duplicate question disclaimer: I also searched the SO site for possible solutions and tried things proposed within different answers but none has helped.

Comment: Learn about 'ajax'

Comment: I'm starting to move on this topic as well. What in Rahul's solution went wrong? You didn't add any messages when you caught the exception.

Comment: I will accept Rahul's answer as the line actually did the job. The problem in my code were the line `facesContext.getApplication().getNavigationHandler().handleNavigation(facesContext, null, "index?faces-redirect=true");` as it navigated away from the page. Deleting the line showed the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The globalOnly switch should work if you add your messages correctly in your backing bean. The client-id must be null in FacesContext.addMessage(...):

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(message));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the return in your catch from `return "index.xhtml";` to `return null;` that's probably causing your page to be fully reloaded so the error status get lost, or you can try addind this line in your `AuthenticationExceptionHanlder#handleException` method

```
facesContext.getCurrentInstance().validationFailed();
```

that should indicate to jsf that there was a validation error an prevent the refresh from happening.

Comment: Unfortunately both did not help.